# simple form of binomial coefficient and product

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, products

I have a binomial coefficient and a prodcut together as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^j}{m!}\binom{m}{j}\prod_{k=1}^{r}(2m-2j-k+1).
\end{align*}
Is there any simpler form of this expression?

Comment: Are you supposed to know the gamma function and its specific properties ?

Comment: anything that can simplify the expression into shorter and simpler form.

Comment: Could you answer my question ? Is this homework or assignment or something else ?

Comment: I am working on one research problem.....its some part of a big formula....